# WPF chart axis lines

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to create an application where different mathematical functions can be displayed on a canvas. I also need to draw an x- and an y-Axis on my canvas with axis labeling. It should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XytA8.jpg

I already created the axis lines, so i just need help with the axis labeling. 
This is what it looks like so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdeHZ.jpg

Here is the code i have used so far:

```
<Line X1="0" Y1="200" X2="600" Y2="200" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"/>
<Line X1="300" Y1="0" X2="300" Y2="400" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Canvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                     Viewport="0,0 20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^ set the size of the tile-->
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <!-- draw a single X -->
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,20"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,0"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <!-- set color and thickness of lines -->
                                <Pen Thickness="0.1" Brush="Black" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
     </Canvas.Background>
```

Comment: well on the way just place a some TextBlock elements like you put down the lines.

Comment: Can you share the code you used to get the current result?

Comment: pretty sure that you're going to need to get into code behind and calculate all of hte points to drop in a TextBlock with the legend and indicator text. Any reason you don't want to use an existing chart control? This should get you started if you don't go that route http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/draw-a-graph-with-labels-wpf-c/